# AMD Laptop immediate wake-up after suspend

Tags: fedora

Probably related to a kernel 6.2+ bug introduced for AMD, as the system also reboots when asked to shut down.

What I already tried after reading all the other posts:

- turned off bluetooth & WiFi
- removed the only external device, USB mouse
- disabled the 2 from the 3 lines that were enabled in /proc/acpi/wakeup

This used to work fine on an older Fedora & kernel, but don't remember which version.

System info:

AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics

`Linux fedora 6.6.8-100.fc38.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Dec 21 04:01:45 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
# cat  /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S0    *disabled
GPP1      S0    *disabled
GPP2      S0    *disabled
GPP3      S0    *disabled
GPP4      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.2
GP17      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
GP19      S0    *disabled
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00


# echo GPP4 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
# echo GP17 > /proc/acpi/wakeup

# cat  /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S0    *disabled
GPP1      S0    *disabled
GPP2      S0    *disabled
GPP3      S0    *disabled
GPP4      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:02.2
GP17      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:08.1
GP19      S0    *disabled
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00


# journalctl -b | grep suspend # after immediate wakeup

Dec 28 12:55:57 fedora systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Dec 28 12:55:57 fedora systemd-sleep[13475]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Dec 28 12:55:57 fedora kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora kernel: PM: suspend devices took 0.099 seconds
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora kernel: PM: suspend exit
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
Dec 28 12:55:59 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
```

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.